# Does NSURLConnection didFailWithError require me to warn the user?

Tags: ios

I know somewhere in the Apple Guidelines it says that if a connection is unavailable to notify the user. But where exactly should this be done?

Until now I've just been showing a `UIAlertView` in the `NSURLConnection didFailWithError` method, but it gets annoying as I use multiple connection objects and if a connection is unavailable the window pops up more than once in some cases.

Do I absolutely have to show a message in the `didFailWithError` method? Or is there a cleaner way to let the user know to check his/her connection?

Comment: No, you do not have to report an error in `didFailWithError`. You should alert the user in whatever appropriate manner makes sense for your app. It's the overall user experience that Apple cares about. Don't completely ignore all errors as this leaves the user wondering why nothing is happening when they expect something to be happening.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided a link to the passage in the documentation that inspired this question. It's hard to imagine that the docs say anywhere that you have to display an alert every single time you have a failed connection.

Comment: Wow, I guess I haven't looked at the guidelines in a while, they look new and different now. The document I remember had numbered sections (ex: 4.1, 4.2 etc...) not anymore apparently. I don't remember the guidelines saying that we had to display an alert everytime a connection fails (that was just my way of doing it until now). It basically said that if an internet connection is unavailable to warn the user somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I absolutely have to show a message in the didFailWithError method?

No, of course not. If your app can tolerate not being able to make the connection there's no reason to bother the user about it. If the failed connection changes the way the app will respond to the user then you should, of course, let the user know somehow. You could use an alert for that, or you might just display an "offline" icon or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to show an alert and you certainly don't need to for every connection failure.  You have a few options:

1. On one failure, retry a couple of times; if all those fail, then notify.
2. Warn on one failure, but disable/throttle warnings for subsequent failures.

Answer (score 1):

I would check whether a connection to the host is possible before trying to connect, you could use a variant of Apple's Reachability code found [here](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability).

If the check succeeds but the connection failed, then the question arises, is the connect absolutely vital for the user to proceed within the app?  If it is vital, alert the user a connection failed, store this state somewhere, and act accordingly, if it's not vital, why tell them at all?  The next time they try to connect, they'll have to go through the same process, which will eventually tell them the host is unreachable.